# PEAR/Digg2: PHP/Linux Installation Issue

Tags: php, pear

I have a VPS running a VPS optimized Debian distro.
I am very new to utilizing a VPS and have next to zero Linux background.

A little background to help:
I went through and apt-get install pear which went through fine.
I attempted to install the dependent services for the Digg api as such:

```
pear install HTTP_Request2
```

This provided an error, I had to install it with:

```
pear install HTTP_Request2-alpha
```

Then I attempted:

```
pear install HTTP_OAuth
```

This provided the same error as above, I installed it eventually with:

```
pear install HTTP_OAuth-alpha
```

So I then successfully installed Digg2 with pear install Services_Digg2

Okay, background over. My issue is that it will not initiate the class as it says the file is not there. The PHP is as simple as this:

```
require_once 'Services/Digg2.php';
$api = new Services_Digg2;
```

I checked my include path as per the error in PHP:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]:
>   Failed opening required 'Services/Digg2.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php')
>   in /var/www/redacted1/data/www/redacted2/index.php on line 3

So I verified that the file was there in Terminal:

http://snapplr.com/tk9r

And I verified that the include path was proper via PHP_Info():

http://snapplr.com/dwk7 <strike>(sorry I can only post one hyperlink as I'm new)</strike>

The error remains.
Hopefully my lengthy intro isn't a hassle and actually helps.

Any incite?

Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a PEAR/PECL package that is in a state other than "stable", you have to specify the full spec for the package:

```
pear install Services_Digg2-alpha #alpha state
pecl install ssh2-0.11.2          #beta state
```

PEAR also takes care of dependencies (usually, but I can confirm in that specific case that it does). You don't have to manually install them.

Now that you have it installed, it should work like you did:

```
include_once 'Services/Digg2.php'
```

However, I'm a little concerned that your code shows `include_once` while the error message you have shows you are using `require_once`. This leads me to believe that the code you posted is not the actual code.

Comment: Sorry, yes I retyped the code into Stack Overflow instead of c&p. I am using require_once (shall edit for posterity). Am trying your suggestion now

Comment: Sorry, did I read that wrong in that you were just giving an example of how to install a package outside of the "stable" state? Or was I supposed to install ssh2? In the latter case, I did attempt is and received and error: http://snapplr.com/0kxj

Comment: @Jeff: yes it was meant as an example, because PEAR and PECL works this way. Anyway, what version of PHP are you using? Do you have the Phar extension? I had this kind of problem when Phar was activated in 5.2. That would cause PHP to spit "No such file or directory" in regular file functions, even if the file existed. Other things can affect this: permissions, open_basedir and other php.ini settings.